# Could not determine the class-path for interface com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject

Tags: android, eclipse, import

When I import an Eclipse project into Android Studio, I got this problem:

`Gradle 'XNote' project refresh failed
    Error:Could not determine the class-path for interface com.android.builder.model.AndroidProject.`

Anyone knows why it happened? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue as you - but just after updating Android Studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Just now i am facing the same problem.

1.Check classpath in build.gradle file.
change to

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

2. then go to gradle-wrapper.properties, and change distributionUrl

> distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

and then rebuild the project. its help for me...
I think this will definitely helps you.

Comment: On mac, it distributionUrl should be "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip"

Answer (score 36):

I have solved this problem.

Google doesn't update ADT any more, so when Eclipse export a project to gradle, it use an old gradle plugin version that Android Studio doesn't support.
[image]

First, you should check the version of gradle plugin that you have installed.
Open Android Studio's installation directory,then open the directory `\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle\`, you will see all version you have installed.
[image]

Then open Android Studio, open tab 'Project -> Gradle Scripts', Edit file `build.gradle`, change the gradle plugin to newest version you have installed, such as 2.3.0:
[image]

[OPTIONAL] This step is not necessary, but if you do not do this, you may see this problem:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'XXX'.
> org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener
```

Check the newest version of gradle you have installed at `C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\.gradle\wrapper\dists`.
[image]
Then open tab 'Project -> Gradle Scripts', edit file `gradle-wrapper.properties`, modify the gradle version(attention: gradle, NOT gradle plugin) to the newest at the last line.
[image]

Finally, click `Build - Clean Project`, done!
If it still warning "Gradle project sync failed...", just click `Try Again`!
[image]

AT THE END, SOMEBODY HELP ME TO TRANSLATE MY ANSWER TO REAL ENGLISH THAT NO grammatical mistakes!!!

Comment: I voted this answer because he posted how to find the version numbers to insert in the two files

Answer (score 9):

Just Update two things:-

1) Update your `Build.gradle` to

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

2) Update Gradle-wrapper.properties: (`Change Android mode > Project mode then Extend Gradle and open Gradle-wrapper.properties`)

Replace `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip`
By

```
distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

This always resolves the issue. may it usefull for you

Answer (score 3):

I got it working after upgrading build tools to version 25.0.0 in build.gradle:

```
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

And change project to use newest gradle version 3.3 with default gradle wrapper (File -> Settings -> Gradle)

Comment: Same here. But I first had to install version 19, then 20, then 25. Don't know why, but it's working now. My guess is the custom controls I'm trying to compile might have been based on Android SDK version 19? Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I removed folder .idea from the project and then restarting the studio automatically manages to all the required folder and gradle work.

Answer (score -1):

First, delete your .gradle folder in the home directory then restart Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Palanivelraghul was right. A Studio has to download the old version. Then it presented 3 different options after it was complete.

Choose the top option **~"Sync with 3.0.1"**.

Event Log:

```
Gradle sync started > Project setup started > Gradle sync finished > Executing tasks:

[:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar] > Gradle build finished.
```